# \shortintertext gives wrong equation numbering when used with hyperref package

Tags: equations, hyperref, numbering

The following code works fine

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{pdftex,colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
\shortintertext{\text{Model 1}}Y_{ij} & = & \beta_{0j}+R_{ij}\\
\shortintertext{\text{Model 2}}\beta_{0j} & = & \gamma_{00}+U_{0j}
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

and give the following output.
[image]

However it starts giving wrong equation numbering when I use

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftex,colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue}
```

See the following code and its output

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftex,colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
\shortintertext{\text{Model 1}}Y_{ij} & = & \beta_{0j}+R_{ij}\\
\shortintertext{\text{Model 2}}\beta_{0j} & = & \gamma_{00}+U_{0j}
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `eqnarray` which is deprecated and produces  bad horizontal spacing. Use  `align` instead. Also, it is needless to load `amstext` since it is loaded by `amsmath`, which is loaded by `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftex,colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\shortintertext{\text{Model 1}}Y_{ij} & = \beta_{0j}+R_{ij}\\
\shortintertext{\text{Model 2}}\beta_{0j} & = \gamma_{00}+U_{0j}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also, using `\shortintertext` at the start of an `align` seem redundant.

Comment: @Werner: Not necessarily: this reduces the vertical spacing from the first equation. Alternatively, one can use the `\useshortskip` from `nccmath`.